# why won't my map show up (but it shows in the dev tools )?

Tags: web-frontend, maplibre-gl

I’m trying to create some vector tiles on my own

and to publish them according to the idea of [protomaps](https://protomaps.com/)

I tried with [this](https://github.com/protomaps/PMTiles/blob/main/js/examples/maplibre.html) example and it worked

This is the map I produced (it’s a bit rough because the style is improvised but the stack did work)

[image: a screenshot of the map I obtained with the mentioned example]

THEN I tried to show the exact same map (the same PMTiles file) BUT locally, without resorting to on line libraries and stylesheet

And what happens is that my project doesn’t work

What is frustrating is that in the Firefox dev tools I hover on the div and a preview of my map DOES SHOW UP !!

As shown here !

[image: a screenshot of my not working front end; in the dev tools the preview DOES come up]

But in the main Firefox window, there’s nothing

My project is [here](https://codeberg.org/abbienormal/protomaps)

Here's th erelevant code

my main.js file

```
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css'
import maplibregl from 'maplibre-gl'

import * as pmtiles from 'pmtiles'

let protocol = new pmtiles.Protocol()
maplibregl.addProtocol("pmtiles",protocol.tile)

let PMTILES_URL = "http://localhost:80/taranto.pmtiles";

const p = new pmtiles.PMTiles(PMTILES_URL);

protocol.add(p);

p.getHeader().then(h => {
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    zoom: h.maxZoom-2,
    center: [h.centerLon, h.centerLat],
    style: {
            version:8,
            sources: {
                      "example_source": {
                          type: "vector",
                          url: "pmtiles://" + PMTILES_URL,
                          attribution: '© <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
                          }
                     },
            layers: [
                        {
                         "id":"landuse",
                         "source": "example_source",
                         "source-layer":"landuse",
                         "type": "fill",
                         "paint": {
                                   "fill-color": "steelblue"
                                  }
                      },
                        {
                         "id":"transportation",
                         "source": "example_source",
                         "source-layer":"transportation",
                         "type": "line",
                         "paint": {
                                   "line-color": "black"
                                  }
                      },
                        {
                         "id":"mask",
                         "source": "example_source",
                         "source-layer":"mask",
                         "type": "fill",
                         "paint": {
                                   "fill-color": "white"
                                  }
                      }
                    ]
                   }
                });
                map.showTileBoundaries = true;
            })
```

and this is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <title>Maplibre App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I’d be really grateful if some kind sould would troubleshoot this for me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the working example, css style for the #map container is specified in the html head section:

```html
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height:100%;  /*usually the map container needs a definite height to show up properly */
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>
```

You will need to include this in your html file (or the `style.css` file referenced in it). Just including `dist/maplibre-gl.css` is not enough.